# Set the correct Datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, kendo-ui, format

I got an multi language Application in c# with a dropdownfield to select the duration of a project

this is how it looks in English

[image]

this is how it looks in German

[image]

the dropdown should always look like the one in German.

here is the code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WorkTimesViewModel>(Model.WorkTimes)
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Project).Title(Html.LabelFor(m => m.Projekt).ToString()).Width(140).ClientTemplate("#: Project.Name #");
          columns.Bound(p => p.Activity).Title(Html.LabelFor(m => m.Aktivität).ToString()).Width(140).ClientTemplate("#: Activity.Name #");
          columns.Bound(p => p.Duration).Title(Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dauer).ToString()).Format("{0:t}").Width(80);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Description).Title(Html.LabelFor(m => m.Bemerkung).ToString()).Width(180);
          columns.Command(command =>
          {
              command.Edit().Text(" ").CancelText(" ").UpdateText(" ");
              command.Destroy().Text(" ");
          }
              ).Width(140);
      })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(Html.LabelFor(m => m.LöschAktivi).ToString()))
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 830px; height: 302px;" })
      .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text(Html.LabelFor(m => m.NeuerArbeitszeiteintrag).ToString()))
      .Scrollable()
      .Selectable(conf => conf.Enabled(true).Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
      .Events(a => a.Edit("onGridEdit"))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Events(e => e.Error("error_handler").RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
                                    .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.Id);
                                        model.Field(p => p.Project).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultProject"] as ProjectViewModel);
                                        model.Field(p => p.Activity).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultActivity"] as ActivityViewModel);
                                        model.Field(p => p.Description).DefaultValue("");
                                        model.Field(p => p.Duration).DefaultValue(new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));

                                    })
```

this is the property in the model

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the duration.
    /// </summary>
    [UIHint("CustomGridTime")]
    public DateTime Duration { get; set; }
```

and here is where I set the value:

```
private static WorkTimesViewModel PrepareModel(WorkTimesViewModel model)
    {
        var newDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
        newDateTime = newDateTime.AddHours(model.Duration.Hour);
        newDateTime = newDateTime.AddMinutes(model.Duration.Minute);
        newDateTime = newDateTime.AddSeconds(model.Duration.Second);
        model.Duration = newDateTime;
        return model;
    }
```

Could somebody help me?

Best regards and Thx

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms or anything else?

Comment: @richej , seems like wpf to me :)

Comment: Oun sorry i forget to say it is KendoUI

Comment: `.Ajax()` doesn't sound like a desktop environment at all. Is this ASP.NET MVC or WebForms?

Comment: You are using a DateTime in a field that is described as a duration, for which TimeSpan would be more suitable. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: This is the first time i've heard that DATES are different in different LANGUAGES lolz

Comment: Okoko.. I missed the Ajax part :) .. Have you tried this [kendo doku](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/configuration/format)

Comment: @richej no it should be an timepicker - no datepicker

the difference between en and de is the displayed format -.-

Comment: @MrLakish Ok. But timepicker also has a 'format' option: (https://dojo.telerik.com/ADAWisEQ)

Comment: @richej yeah if seen this,thx  - but to be honest - i don't know how to implement it, to this actual code :/

Comment: Could this be just a CSS problem? I'd imagine you can fix this with some class with a `minimum-width` or something

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto no it is not the problem of the css. the problem i have is the input in the dropdown.
the time should always been looking, like in german i.e. 0:15; 0:30 
this should be the duration in english the same looks i.e. 12:15 AM, 12:30 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Kendo's culture using JavaScript. Set the culture globally in the _Layout.cshtml file or locally by adding this in your view. It should apply the correct format to your TimePicker input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    kendo.culture("de-DE");
</script>
```

See Kendo UI documentation for more information:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview

OR

Create an [Editor Template](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates) named CustomGridTime.cshtml in the "Views > [WorkTimes?] > EditorTemplates" folder. Create the EditorTemplates folder if it doesn't exist.

```
@model DateTime
@Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m => m).Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern)
```

Then change your grid column.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Duration).Title(Html.LabelFor(m => m.Dauer).ToString()).Format("{0:" + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern + "}").EditorTemplateName("CustomGridTime").Width(80);
```

Comment: The Problem ist, i only need that one field in german style - all the other fields should be dynamicly

Answer (score 0):

You could force culture of your current Thread like this :

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

Please refer to MSDN documentation for more information : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What? How will this change at all how a component is rendered? Please read the question before answering random stuff

Comment: I supposed that the third party component is using culture to display correct datetime format... As the original poster said : "the dropdown should always look like the one in German.".

Comment: thats correct - the appliacation is dynamic. the user can setup his favorite language in his settings. but this dropdown should always look the same. But it change - because of the language change.

Comment: Did you try to pass lang="de-DE" (or might be just "de") to HtmlAttributes ?